# Python: How to find continuous time intervals in list of time objects?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have a dictionary whose key is date object and value is a list of time objects.

```
timeSlots = {
    datetime.date(2014, 12, 11): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
        datetime.time(8, 30),
        datetime.time(9, 0),
        datetime.time(9, 30),
        datetime.time(12, 0),
        datetime.time(12, 30),
        datetime.time(13, 0),
        datetime.time(13, 30),
        datetime.time(14, 0),
        datetime.time(14, 30)
    ],
    datetime.date(2014, 12, 12): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
        datetime.time(8, 30),
        datetime.time(9, 0),
        datetime.time(9, 30),
        datetime.time(12, 0),
        datetime.time(12, 30),
        datetime.time(13, 0),
        datetime.time(13, 30),
        datetime.time(14, 0),
        datetime.time(14, 30)
    ]
}
```

Input : 30 minutes
Output : {datetime.date(2014, 12, 11): [90, 150], datetime.date(2014, 12, 12): [90, 150]}

How it is calculated :

1. assume my interval is 30 minutes as provided in input.
2. Take first list of time slot. Start seeing that difference between 8:00:00 and 8:30:00 is 30 minutes which is same as input received, so again go to next element of list which is 9:00:00(same case 8:30:00 and 9:00:00 has 30 min difference) and so on.
3. Stop at 12:00:00 as difference is more than 30 min of previous element in list which is 9:30:00.
4. Calculate difference between 8:00:00 and 9:30:00 and return in minutes which is 90 minutes.
5. Continue the process and you will get the output.

Hope I am clear.

What is the best way to do this ?

TIA

Comment: What form do you provide the interval in?

Comment: In minutes. integer format.

Comment: Can you tell how is the time between 8:00 to 9:30 different from say, 9:00 to 10:30? Are you sure you are having enough information about these times in the `timeSlots` dict?

Comment: Both are same. But I want to find the continuous time objects with particular minute as intervals. And I take the start and end time objects and find the minutes between two. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I am also trying to understand this but it is quite unclear.

In your example, do you pass in 30 as the argument representing the intervals? What is returned?

What is the input and output, your provided example doesn't help.

Comment: @theLeanDeveloper Perhaps you could provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @theLeanDeveloper Do you also need the difference between the intervals that were bigger than the desired input interval? Is that what '150' means in your example output?

Comment: @HernánErasmo No. That is difference between other continuous time objects: From 12:00:00 to 14:30:00 which has 30 min interval in between time objects

Comment: @theLeanDeveloper Sorry, perhaps I'm not thinking about this the right way, but I see no gap of 150 minutes between 12:00 and 14:30 in any of those two timeSlots. Both of them have elements for 13:00 and 13:30

Comment: @HernánErasmo Ya there is no gap. Thats the point. between both there is continuous interval of 30 minutes. And I am taking the difference between 12:00 and 14:30 which is 150. I urge you read the question again where I have explained this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got exactly what you're saying, but try this function. It returns a generator that splits on your wanted indices (longer than `interval`) for each key in your `dict`.

```
import datetime

timeSlots = {
    datetime.date(2014, 12, 11): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
        datetime.time(8, 30),
        datetime.time(9, 0),
        datetime.time(9, 30),
        datetime.time(12, 0),
        datetime.time(12, 30),
        datetime.time(13, 0),
        datetime.time(13, 30),
        datetime.time(14, 0),
        datetime.time(14, 30)]
    ,datetime.date(2   interval = 30


    def get_consec(time_slots):
        for key, value in time_slots.iteritems():
            print "date: %s" % key
            last_index = 0
            diffs = zip(value[:-1], value[1:])
            print "diffs: %s" % diffs
            index = None
            for index in range(len(diffs)):
                start = diffs[index][0]
                end = diffs[index][1]
                if (end.hour * 60 + end.minute) - (start.hour * 60 + start.minute) > interval:
                    print "splitting: %s"  % str((start ,end))
                    yield value[last_index: index+1]
                    last_index = index + 1
            if index and index != last_index:
                yield value[last_index: index + 2]
            else:
                yield value

    print list(get_consec(timeSlots))014, 12, 12): [
            datetime.time(8, 0),
            datetime.time(8, 30),
            datetime.time(9, 0),
            datetime.time(9, 30),
            datetime.time(12, 0),
            datetime.time(12, 30),
            datetime.time(13, 0),
            datetime.time(13, 30),
            datetime.time(14, 0),
            datetime.time(14, 30)
        ]
    ,datetime.date(2014, 12, 13): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
    ]
    ,datetime.date(2014, 12, 14): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
        datetime.time(8, 30),
    ]

    ,datetime.date(2014, 12, 15): [
        datetime.time(8, 0),
        datetime.time(8, 40),
    ]
}

interval = 30

def get_consec(time_slots):
    for key, value in time_slots.iteritems():
        print "date: %s" % key
        last_index = 0
        diffs = zip(value[:-1], value[1:])
        print "diffs: %s" % diffs
        index = None
        for index in range(len(diffs)):
            start = diffs[index][0]
            end = diffs[index][1]
            if (end.hour * 60 + end.minute) - (start.hour * 60 + start.minute) > interval:
                print "splitting: %s"  % str((start ,end))
                yield (key, value[last_index: index+1], )
                last_index = index + 1
        if index is not None:
            print "finished with last: %d, index: %d" % (last_index, index)
            yield (key, value[last_index: index+2], )
        else:
            print "no iteration for %s" % value
            yield (key, value, )

print '\n'.join(map(str, list(get_consec(timeSlots))))
```

### Edit

Added full code for your convenience to test. It works for some cases, make sure to add more!

Comment: I modified it a bit according to my problem and its working now. Thanks for direction. I am accepting this answer.

Comment: Yeah, it has some bugs. I've added some testing on my side and it still has a few cases it doesn't catch. I'll modify if I get it done soon.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll be the first to admit that perhaps this is not the most pythonic way to do this, but here's my solution:

```
import datetime

def get_difference(d, times):
    first = datetime.datetime.combine(d, times[0])
    second = datetime.datetime.combine(d, times[1])
    return second - first

def solution(ts, interval):
    results = []
    outputDict = {}
    acc = datetime.timedelta()
    for key in ts:
        for item in range(len(ts[k])-1):
            delta = get_difference(key, ts[key][item:item+2])
            if delta > interval:
                results.append(acc)
                acc = datetime.timedelta()
            else:
                acc += delta
        results.append(acc)
        acc = datetime.timedelta()
        outputDict[key] = [result.total_seconds() / 60 for result in results]
        results = []
    return outputDict
```

It gives the exact output you described:

```
>>> solution(timeSlots, datetime.timedelta(0, 1800))   #Interval needs to be in seconds
{datetime.date(2014, 12, 12): [90.0, 150.0], datetime.date(2014, 12, 11): [90.0, 150.0]}
```